# IE Not Loading Correct Mime-Type From IIS Via Mod_JK

Tags: tomcat, internet-explorer, iis, mod-jk

I have an application developed on Wildfly.  To allow external users to access it, I have set up an IIS server in our DMZ.  I configured the Tomcat JK Connector (isapi_redirect.dll) to redirect incoming traffic to the internal application server via AJP.  When I access the login page going through IIS, CSS, JavaScript and images do not always load correctly.  I have taken a look at the network traffic and IE 11 is receiving mime-types of text/html for CSS, JavaScript and image files.  The page always displays fine in Chrome and Firefox.  The mime-types are handled correctly in those browsers.  But for IE, the mime-type is not handled correctly.  Also, if I browse to the internal application correctly, everything displays fine.  So I am thinking it is an IIS/IE issue or a IIS/IE/Tomcat JK Connector issue.  But IE must be part of the issue since Chrome and Firefox handle it correctly.

I am using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.  I have looked through many posts here and have not found anything that fits my situation.  I took a look at the mime-types configured in IIS and they CSS, JavaScript and the image mime-types are present and correct.

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE? I found a [similar issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192742/some-images-are-not-displayed-in-ie) and you could refer to it and try the solutions in it. It says that **X-Content-Type-Options nosnif** causes the issue. You could also try to remove this line `<add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>` in `Web.config` and test it again.

Comment: The only error I get in the console is a javascript error indicating that the javascript could not be loaded.  It is also coming in with a Content-Type of text/html.  I removed the X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff response header but it did not make a difference.  I refresh the page and some elements are interpreted correctly but not the entire page.  I could refresh it again and those same elements are no longer interpreted.

Comment: Are you using IE10 or IE11, if you are using IE 10, please try it with IE11.

Comment: I am using IE11.  I am still working on it but not making much progress.